# Make all files under a directory read-only without changing permissions?

Tags: linux

I'm a beginner in linux.I have a question on filesystem that is it possible to make all files under a directory read-only without changing permissions?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. The write **permission** grants the ability to write a file. So that you need to **change** it anyway to make the file read-only for specific user or group of users.

You'd probably like to read [this](https://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4124/) at spare time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have suitable privileges, and if the filesystem is not critical to the machine (do not try this with "/", your root filesystem), you can remount the filesystem read-only.  The details differ slightly from one system to another, but a useful discussion is found here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/296331/how-to-mount-a-hard-disk-as-read-only-from-the-terminal

that applies to Linux and BSDs.

Because this does not actually modify the *files*, you can undo this by remounting the filesystem again, with read/write permissions, e.g., "rw" where the "ro" option was used.  For specific information you should read the manpage(s) for mount and fstab for the system you are using.